# How to pass "weights" column name as a variable in R's lm?

Tags: r, lm

The code below creates a linear model with R's lm, then a weighted model with a weights column.  Finally, I try to pass in the weight column name with a variable `weight_col` and that fails.  I'm pretty sure it's looking for "weight_col" in df, then the caller's environment, finds a variable of length 1, and the lengths don't match.

How do I get it to use weight_col as a name for the weights column in df?

I've tried several combinations of things without success.

```
> df <- data.frame(
   x=c(1,2,3),
   y=c(4,5,7),
   w=c(1,3,5)
 )
> lm(y ~ x, data=df)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      2.333        1.500  

> lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=w)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = w)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)            x  
      1.947        1.658  

> weight_col <- 'w'
> lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=weight_col)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = weight_col,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.6.3 (2020-02-29)"
```

Comment: In your example, `weight_col` is just a single string, `"w"`. It is not a reference to a column in `df`. Perhaps `weights=df[[weight_col]]`? The first use if `weights=w`, which is very different from your second example which resolves to `weights="w"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the data frame name with extractor operator:

```
lm(y ~ x, data = df, weights = df[[weight_col]])
```

Or you can use function `get`:

```
lm(y ~ x, data = df, weights = get(weight_col))
```

Comment: Thanks! For reasons I don't understand, in the real (more complicated) code it said, "object 'df' not found" with `[[]]`s, but `get` worked. It may have been multiple levels of function calls?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `[[` to extract the value of the column

```
lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=df[[weight_col]])
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   summarise(model  = list(y ~ x, weights = .data[[weight_col]]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first example if `weights = w`, which is using non-standard evaluation to find `w` in the context of `df`. So far, this is normal for interactive use.

Your second set is `weights = weight_col` which resolves to `weights = "w"`, which is very different. There is nothing in R's non-standard (or standard) evaluation in which that makes sense.

As I said in my comment, use the standard-evaluation form with `[[`.

```r
lm(y ~ x, data=df, weights=df[[weight_col]])
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x, data = df, weights = df[[weight_col]])
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)            x  
#       1.947        1.658
```